# Boost Asio Peek and Completion Condition

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I am using Boost Asio to set up a socket connection.  I would like to peek at the data in the buffer without consuming it, and I would like to use a completion condition to ensure that I could stop the blocking call if necessary.

I can get the peek functionality from [basic_stream_socket::receive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/receive/overload3.html):

```
template<
    typename MutableBufferSequence>
std::size_t receive(
    const MutableBufferSequence & buffers,
    socket_base::message_flags flags,
    boost::system::error_code & ec);
```

One of the possible message_flags is [basic_stream_socket::message_peek](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/message_peek.html).  However, this call blocks until at least one byte is read or an error occurs.  I can get the completion condition functionality from [read](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload3.html):

```
template<
    typename SyncReadStream,
    typename MutableBufferSequence,
    typename CompletionCondition>
std::size_t read(
    SyncReadStream & s,
    const MutableBufferSequence & buffers,
    CompletionCondition completion_condition,
    boost::system::error_code & ec);
```

I can provide a completion_condition method which checks if the call should be aborted before continuing.

My question is this: Is there a way to get a message_flags parameter and a completion_condition parameter in the same method call?

Comment: why not use async operations, then you don't need to worry - no calls will be blocking, and you'll be notified when there is data.

Comment: I would still have the problem of not being able to stop the pending operation if needed.  I could do an async operation if it had both the ability to peek and to provide a completion condition, but if I used an async method (like async_receive) I'm not sure how to cancel the operation if necessary.

Comment: For a given socket, you can cancel outstanding asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to peek at the data in the buffer without consuming it,
>   and I would like to use a completion condition to ensure that I could
>   stop the blocking call if necessary.

Don't do this. Use asynchronous methods such as `async_read()` and `async_write()`. To stop outstanding asynchronous operations, use [`cancel()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel.html).